# Threading, tkinter and winsound

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, multiprocessing, winsound

I am trying to create a program that plays sound and shows the wave. However, when I try to call the `multiprocessing.Process` method so that I can cancel the playback if the user clicks the play button before the sound has finished. However, instead of calling my `actualPlaySound` method, it seems to recall my code and another `tkinter` window opens. Please help!

```
from tkinter import *
import math, time, threading, winsound, os, multiprocessing
def update ():
    global modded
    if not modded:
        modded = True
        stringAmplitude.set (str (amplitude.get ()))
        stringFrequency.set (str (frequency.get ()))
        modded = False
    c.delete (ALL)
    width, height = c.winfo_width (), c.winfo_height () / 2
    freq = frequency.get ()
    c.create_line (0, 25, width, 25)
    c.create_polygon (15, 10, 0, 25, 15, 40)
    c.create_polygon (width - 15, 10, width, 25, width - 15, 40)
    if freq <= 100: c.create_text (width / 2, 15, text = "1 second")
    elif freq <= 1000:
        c.create_text (width / 2, 15, text = "10 milliseconds")
        freq = freq / 100
    else:
        c.create_text (width / 2, 15, text = "1 millisecond")
        freq = freq / 1000
    ampl, freq = amplitude.get () ** 0.5, freq * math.pi * 2
    for x in range (width):
        c.create_line (x, math.sin (x * freq / width) * ampl * (height - 30 if height > 30 else 0) / 10 + (height if height > 35 else 35), x + 1, math.sin ((x + 1) * freq / width) * ampl * (height - 30 if height > 30 else 0) / 10 + (height if height > 35 else 35))
def stringUpdate ():
    global modded
    if not modded:
        modded = True
        try: amplitude.set (float (stringAmplitude.get ()))
        except: pass
        try: frequency.set (float (stringFrequency.get ()))
        except: pass
        modded = False
def playSound ():
    global p
    if not p or not p.is_alive ():
        p = multiprocessing.Process (target = actualPlaySound)
        p.start ()
    else: p.terminate ()
def actualPlaySound ():
    freq = int (frequency.get ())
    if freq < 37:
        l.config (text = "Too low!")
    elif freq > 32767:
        l.config (text = "Too high!")
    else:
        l.config (text = "Playing...")
        winsound.Beep (freq, 5000)
        l.config (text = "Played!")
modded, p = False, None
root = Tk ()
root.title ("Waves")
amplitude, frequency, stringAmplitude, stringFrequency = DoubleVar (), DoubleVar (), StringVar (), StringVar ()
amplitude.set (50)
frequency.set (1000)
stringAmplitude.set ("50")
stringFrequency.set ("1000")
amplitude.trace ("w", lambda a, b, c: update ())
frequency.trace ("w", lambda a, b, c: update ())
stringAmplitude.trace ("w", lambda a, b, c: stringUpdate ())
stringFrequency.trace ("w", lambda a, b, c: stringUpdate ())
root.bind ("<Configure>", lambda event: update ())
Label (root, text = "Frequency").grid (row = 0, column = 0)
Scale (root, from_ = 50, to = 32000, orient = "horizontal", variable = frequency).grid (row = 1, column = 0)
Entry (root, textvariable = stringFrequency).grid (row = 2, column = 0)
Frame (root, height = 50).grid (row = 3, column = 0)
Label (root, text = "Amplitude (this doesn't\nchange playback volume)").grid (row = 4, column = 0)
Scale (root, orient = "horizontal", variable = amplitude).grid (row = 5, column = 0)
Entry (root, textvariable = stringAmplitude).grid (row = 6, column = 0)
l = Label (root, text = "Ready to go!")
l.grid (row = 7, column = 0)
Button (root, text = "Play", command = lambda: threading.Thread (target = playSound).start ()).grid (row = 8, column = 0)
c = Canvas (root, bg = "white", width = 500, height = 400)
c.grid (row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 20, sticky = "nsew")
Grid.columnconfigure (root, 1, weight = 1)
for y in range (20): Grid.rowconfigure (root, y, weight = 1)
update ()
root.mainloop ()
os._exit (0)
```

Comment: The `multiprocessing` module on Windows absolutely requires that there be NO top-level code in your script outside of an `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Comment: I added this as recommended but it still didn't run my `actualPlaySound` method